# Is there a way to craft Podzol in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just want to build a house with Podzol on top, but I don't want to use my Creative Inventory to get it. How can I acquire Podzol?

Answer (score 11):

No, [podzol](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Podzol)'s not craftable. You'd have to harvest it with a Silk Touch–enchanted tool from the rare [Mega Taiga biome](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mega_Taiga#Mega_Taiga).

Answer (score 3):

Since 1.14 I believe, podzol doesn't require finding a megataiga. You still can't craft it, but producing it is actually pretty easy - you need a silk touch tool (optimally shovel), a lot of dirt or grass (eh, just being in a grassy biome suffices), some spruce saplings, and optionally a bunch of bonemeal and an axe. Find (or build) a relatively flat, large dirt or grass area. Plant a 2x2 square of spruce saplings with no blocks neighboring them (no tall grass, flowers, snow layers etc). Bonemeal one of the saplings a couple times (or just wait long enough), and the four will grow into a tall spruce, while converting a lot of grass/dirt around into podzol. Gather the podzol using the silk touch tool, then repeat the process (optionally first chopping down the spruce for wood and gathering more saplings as the leaves decay).